# Twilio is being blocked by proxy server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

Hi I am creating a project in Visual studiio asp.net MVC and the university proxy server is blocking my sms from going out to the cellphone. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Twilio developer evangelist here. Sorry to hear you're having trouble. When you say it's being blocked, do you mean the messages aren't even getting to twilio?

Comment: the sms are not sending to the phone

Comment: Yeah, i understand that, but are they getting to Twilio at all? You can see that by looking at https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/messages

Comment: Is this just with Twilio or with other SMS gateways as well?